# Function not returning modified length of string

Tags: c++, string, function, return, stdstring

Why doesn't the function return the updated length of the strings rather than showing the length of those strings that were passed into the function?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int number_needed(string a, string b) {
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<b.length();j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==b[j]){
                {
                a[i]='\0';
                b[j]='\0';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
    return a.length()+b.length();

}

int main(){
    string x;
    cin >> x;
    string y;
    cin >> y;
    cout << number_needed(x, y) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

input:

> weasaa
>   asjdsa

output:

> wea jds
>   12 (returned value from the func number_needed)

expected:

> return value of func number_needed to be :

```
wea jds
6
```

Comment: Why would you think the length of the strings has changed? You only overwrote the contents

Comment: don't write in c if you use cpp. [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Comment: As an aside, `using namespace std;` is a bad idea. Or do you know everything which is in there, might be in there, or might someday be in there?

Comment: @Deduplicator I agree that in actual production code `using namespace std` is bad practice, but man if it's not easier on the eyes in toy examples.

Comment: C-style strings and the C++ std::string class are completely different things and you can't treat one the same as the other.

Answer (score 3):

A [`std::string`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a *counted* string, not a *NUL-terminated* one.

Thus, changing any arbitrary character won't ever change its length.

If you want to change its size, use [`.resize(newlength)`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize).

Comment: how would resize() help if '/0' is the character. Resize() just only removes last few characters.

Comment: Because `resize()` would resize the string. You seem to be under the misconception that the characters contained in the string have anything to do with the size of the string. Maybe you should try stepping through your code with a debugger, because you're clearly suffering some misconceptions about how `std::string` works.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do inside the if is:

```
    if (a[i] == b[j])
    {
            a.erase(i, 1);
            b.erase(j--, 1); //decrement j so we can check the new char at b[j]
    }
```

This removes 1 element (change the number depending on your needs) from each string starting (and including, of course) at index `i`. A string can contain any number of '\0', this will not affect the size. If it's a character, then it will count towards the total size of the string.

Comment: My bad, b.erase() should use index `j` instead of `i`. It should work now. By the way, you will need to check if you erased the last element of `a`, since it could cause errors trying to compare a non-existent element and `b[i]`.

Comment: Great, works now. But how j-- changed the story? I had used index j with b.erase but wasnt even close

Comment: Let's say your j is 2 and you delete b[2]. The remainder of the string will be shifted left to fill the deleted spot, so b[3] will now be b[2] and so on. However, the next iteration will change j to 3, so you won't be able to check the former b[3] (now b[2]) and will start with the former b[4] (now b[3] or b[j]). This is why we have to go back one iteration (j--) to check the whole string. Another way to solve this is by changing the if to a while loop, so you constantly check the current b[j] until it is no longer equal to a[i].

Answer (score 0):

What you want to accomplish may be delete repeating letters in `std::string` **A** and **B**, but you only change it to `\0`,which does not change string length.Also, your results according to your code, should be:

```
we\0\0\0a \0\0\0jds\0
12
```

So in your console, it may look like:

```
we   a    jds 
12
```

But if you want your expected result, check:

```
for (auto Itr_a = a.begin(); Itr_a != a.end(); ++Itr_a)
{
    for (auto Itr_b = b.begin(); Itr_b != b.end();)
    {
        if (*Itr_a == *Itr_b)
        {
            Itr_a = a.erase(Itr_a);
            Itr_b = b.erase(Itr_b);
        }
        else
            ++Itr_b;
    }
}
```

> Output:

```
wea jds
6
```

Comment: tried this, didnt work out for me. Could you just do it with my code?

Comment: Did you replace your for loop with mine in the function?

Answer (score 0):

[`length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) (which is the same as the preferred `size` method) returns:

> The number of `CharT` elements in the `string`, i.e. `std::distance(begin(), end())`

Since [`string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) does not invalidate iterators this means that you could assign a null to every character in a string and it wouldn't change the length.

---

You can use [`count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) to find the number of non-`'\0'` characters in a `string`. You can use it like this: `count_if(begin(a), end(a), [](const auto& i){ return i != '\0'; })`

With this change your `return`-statement then would look like this:

```
return count_if(begin(a), end(a), [](const auto& i){ return i != '\0'; }) + count_if(begin(b), end(b), [](const auto& i){ return i != '\0'; })
```

---

**EDIT:**

A couple comments can be made here:

1. With the exception of the `cout`-statement `number_needed` could be replaced by [`set_symetric_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference)
2. If the `cout`-statement is needed, 2 [`set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) statements should be considered
3. If neither of the above are desirable, the `if`-statement should end with a `break` and the 2 parameters should be passed by const-reference.

Comment: @AvneetSingh If you click on the `count_if` hyperlink in the answer it'll take you to the reference page for the function. But in layman's terms it will iterate over every character in the string if the lambda returns true for that character it increments the count that is returned. The lambda is simply checking if the character is non-`'\0'`.